Deciding between Solang and Seahorse
What are the major differences or pros/cons in these two languages? As someone trying to avoid learning Rust and wants to use the most capable/safest language.

This is an opinion-based question, but as an overview, Seahorse transpiles Python to Rust code. This means that you get a lot of the benefits of Rust without having to write Rust, at the cost of more limited language.
On the other hand, Solang is Solidity code that goes directly to the Solang compiler, so it has all of the features and issues of Solidity.
As for some other options, you can also write your program in C or Zig!
